# Is my fast still valid if i swallowed blood

Tags: sawm, ramadan

Asalam alaykum. When I woke up this morning I tasted blood in my mouth. I usually bleed from 2 places in my mouth so I put my nail there and checked if the was blood (i didnt see any) so I swallowed it. I also swallowed it a few times before testing it as I was having doubts. Also sometimes during ramadan my mouth randomly tastes like blood even if I am not bleeding. That is also another reason I swallowed it. Well a few seconds after, I tasted a  lot of blood and went to rinse my mouth in the sink and saw that there was blood in my saliva. I was really sleepy at the time I first tasted the blood and I think that affected my judgment in swallowing my saliva even if there could've been blood in it. Considering that I swallowed the saliva intentionally (multiple times) even though there was a chance that blood was in my mouth, is my fast invalidated? If it is invalidated what is the punishment for it. Jazakumallahu khair.